# I am getting duplicates in UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am getting duplicates of my array, and wrongly displayed cells in this method:

Here I am initializing the array, and adding it to the tableView:

```
NSArray *sectionsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Location", @"Front Post", @"Front Fixing", @"Front Footplate", @"Rear Post", @"Read Fixing", @"Rear Footplate", @"Horizontal Bracing", @"Diagonal Bracing", @"Front Beam", @"Front Lock", @"Rear Beam", @"Rear Lock", @"Guard", @"Accessories", @"Comments", @"Off load ref", @"Loc Empty", @"Loc Affected", nil];
[_tableArray setObject:sectionsArray atIndexedSubscript:2];
[_tableView reloadData];
```

For some weird reason there are always the 4th object that is messed up, and is either duplicated, or do not have the views from IB. Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EntryCell"];
        cell.tag = indexPath.row;
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        [label setText:[[_tableArray objectAtIndex:2] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
return cell;
}
```

I have logged the string `[[_tableArray objectAtIndex:2] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`, and it logs the right string.

Comment: try to remove `cell.tag = indexPath.row;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `cell.tag = indexPath.row;`

Because you are reusing the cells and assigning the `tag` will confuse it. For example, for 2nd row you assign tag = 2 and then when you scroll down you assign tag = 6 to that same row.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
else
{

 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```